# Audio going out of sync when using setpts and tempo in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to slow down a video and its audio at the same time (mp4). I have tried doing the audio and video separately with code similar to the command below, but still get the same effect.

The audio slowly goes out of sync with the video after roughly 30 seconds (audio goes faster).

> -i "INPUT" -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=1.1*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=0.9[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" "OUTPUT"

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a classical math error: *"An increase of 10% (i.e. `x 1.1`) can be compensated by a reduction of 10% (`x 0.9`)"* No! To compensate a `x 1.1`, you have to divide by `1.1`.

Answer (score 7):

You're not altering the speed of the audio and video by the same amount.

Video is being slowed to 1.0/1.1 = 90.91%

So, specify the same for the audio, using fractions, for precision

```
-i "INPUT" -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=1.1*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=(1/1.1)[a]" -map "[v]"" -map "[a]" "OUTPUT"
```

Comment: @Mulya, I am trying to increase speed 3 times setpts=0.33*PTS, how to calculate corresponding atempo speed?

Comment: `atempo` only goes upto 2.0, so you'll need two calls: `atempo=1.5,atempo=2` where `1.5 x 2 = 3`

Comment: @Gyan I need  fast video 4x speed with audio also, as per `atempo` is goes up only 2.0, then how can i speedup with 4x audio? Please Help me

Comment: Recent versions can go up to 100. Upgrade.

Comment: Heh, so https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video needs an update :)

Comment: Great answer on using the fractional; it makes all the difference between "works" vs "sound is desynced (even when using a number with many decimal digits)". Thank you!